# Upload image to FTP server by php file with Ionic 3

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

**This function `pickupimage()`**

```
   pickupimage(){

         const options: CameraOptions = {
         quality: 100,
         destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
         encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
         mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
         sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        }

         this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {

           let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
           this.resim = base64Image;
           this.sendimage();
         }, (err) => {

         });



   }
```

**This function `sendimage()`**:

```
 sendimage(){

      let postData = new FormData();
      postData.append('photo',this.resim);


      let headers: any = new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }),
      options: any = { key: "kontrol"},
      url: any = "http://.../sendimage.php";

      this.http
      .post(url, JSON.stringify(postData), headers)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(res => {

      });

}
```

**sendimage.php**

```
<?php

  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT');

  $imagedata = $_FILES['photo'];

  $ftp_server = "xx.xx.xx.xx";
  $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
  $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, 'MyFTPusername', 'MyFTPpassword');

  ftp_put($ftp_conn, "/public_html/img/".$_FILES['photo']['name'], $imagedata, FTP_ASCII);

  ftp_close($ftp_conn);

  echo json_encode($imagedata);

?>
```

I want to post image. I want to use php for my FTP server. It does not work.

How can I do, taken photo with camera and upload to my ftp server with php file?

Comment: What do you mean by *it does not work ?*

Comment: it means, i can not upload image with that codes

Comment: But what's the error you get ? We need a specific problem to help you. Please take at this to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i dont know what is error? you tell me please :)

Comment: Sorry but that's not how this website works, take a look at the link I gave you

Comment: This question needs a [mcve]. It is unlikely that anyone could help unless that is provided.